# What is the difference between these function signatures in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

Update: Besides the below solution, setting `strictBindCallApply` to `true` for TS compiler allows `.bind` to preserve function signatures, which is the easiest way to fix this issue.

I'm working on an old codebase that's the definition of callback hell, so to make things easier I'm promisifying some methods on a class. I made a `PromiseObject` type to hold the promisified methods, defined as

```
export type PromiseObject = {
  [fn: string]: (...args: any) => Promise<any>
}
```

And then in the class I started with

```
promises: PromiseObject = {
   fn1: util.promisify(this.fn1)
}
```

Which worked great and TypeScript inferred the parameter and return types for the promisified function.
But then I had a method of an object that would be created during execution of a method on the main class, so I promisified it like this:

```
promises: PromiseObject = {
   fn1: util.promisify(this.fn1)
   fn2: (provider: IdentityProvider, user: AssertedUser) =>
            util.promisify(provider.getGroups)(user)
}
```

And TypeScript complained because this `fn2` didn't match the `[fn: string]: (...args: any) => Promise<any>` signature. I don't really understand how fn1 and fn2 have meaningfully different signatures; both of them take `...args: any` and both return `Promise<any>`. fn2 just has an extra step before it returns its promise. What am I missing?

UPDATE
T.J. Crowder had it right, I didn't need `PromiseObject` at all, removed that part and everything's working.

After removing, I also ensured proper binding with the following (see [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wK42AGzgMyghDgHItdSAoKmATzAFM4BBVVR2RgEwFUOocALxwA3lTiTMAgHbIQjAFxxUMKMBkBzKgF9aDZgEluABSIA3YN07CxEqZsYwA4kQxhUygBQYBytgIwPPycADRwAMYARt6cUMrIMnThmm4eyjIYIFGcANoAugCUwgB8cOYQVsVCZRVWujQROGjoALJ0AMLN7HZSBDIAjF7IUJrKqupa4dGxUPEoSeFQjJ4qahqa1bWV3MXifX3RXpk4OOEjm-aSen1g6ubIQXB3xMAc6CL7B5L4g8owAAs3gA6KIaaxQHzYHDAl4gN7AfB0LyAkG-AaFcKo1CYq4HX4AJm8vk4-nYnCCfAE4RelghymMZggdM4Wzg2NB4M4UNwsKI8NQiORtKsnGBjhcaRxNIsoqghR8AkKeJuUjuwAeTzBMghAB4ACrhXglLxwt6MABiMm8F2U%20rZTIFjF1xqxQNQLFGCSSezxhwgMlUcCiEAwOtsZo4Vs5OpR7s9l2%20kmWMAwUBkwdD4bQ7IMEHwz355qtKt0QA)):

```
import * as util from 'util'

type AssertedUser = {
    username: string
}
type IdProvider = {
    getGroups: (user: AssertedUser, cb: (err: any, groups: number[]) => void) => void
}

class MyClass {
    fn1(arg: string, cb: (err: any, res: string) => void) {
        cb(null, arg)
    }
    private promises = {
        fn1: this.binder(util.promisify(this.fn1), this),
        fn2: (user: AssertedUser, provider: IdProvider) => this.binder(util.promisify(provider.getGroups), provider)(user)
    }
    private binder<T, U>(promiseFn: (arg: T) => Promise<U>, thisArg: any) {
        const bound = promiseFn.bind(thisArg)
        return bound as typeof promiseFn
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Which worked great and TypeScript inferred the parameter and return types for the promisified function."* Really? That's...surprising (to me). Can you do a [TypeScript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) showing that? [My guess at what it would look like](https://tsplay.dev/Nr5o5w) does not infer parameter types.

Comment: Using `any`, you don't get proper types at all

Comment: Without seeing `util.promisify`, it looks like `fn1` is a function that returns a promise and `fn2` is a function that returns a function that returns a promise.

Comment: Can you provide the error displayed by TypeScript?

Comment: @Etheryte - It's from the Node.js API.

Comment: ...Whereas **without** `PromiseObject`, [it does handle it](https://tsplay.dev/N9Ea1N) (thanks to the types on `promisify`).

Comment: (But I think you're losing `this`. You'd need to both `promisify` and `bind`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder when I add .bind after, like util.promisify(...).bind(this), the type of the function becomes any. These methods are all private and will only be executed inside this class, so do i really need bind?

Comment: @the_midnight_developer - It depends on several factors. Do you need to use `this` within the functions? (For instance, to call another function on `this.promises`?) And also, are they declared as methods (shared via the prototype) or created as arrow functions? If the latter, you don't need `bind`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I do need to use this. I tried creating a variable for the promisified function, and another for the result of calling .bind(this) on the promisified function, then returning the bound version `as typeof fn`, all inside an IIFE. Does that work?
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wK42AGzgMyghDgHItdSAoKgYxzXQFkBPAYQdXQG8q5+CAOwCMACmRQA5gC44qGFGCDJAGji0ARrNEBTKFFnJBLNVB2pZ8xcoCUcALwA+OADcIwACZ3eA3+o2ighg4OGoSkjZ8AgC+Ufxgii7IMDpwCcTAqOYOcD5+-Pgi2qJ2Trlx+QK0EILyQjkUOAB06SCZwPgsojAAFplNhcKRlX7VtfAaEBiCHjmFTRpKHt19qMMjAmYwGFCCcJPTs2hwMCxgOhD4QhW+0TYlFbHRQA

Comment: @the_midnight_developer - I have to admit, I kind of like that implementation, though extracting it out into a reusable utility function may prove difficult or at least tedious (all those overloads on `promisify`!). It only works because of the type assertion, and type assertions are generally not a good idea, but in **this** case you're just saying that you know the function meets the contract of the promisified function, which you do know, so seems good to me...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Added it to the question, let me know what you think, and thank you

Comment: As a meta comment, instead of editing your solution into your question, it would be better to add an answer containing the fix. That way other people stumbling upon the question in the future can easily see there is an answer.